# How to store dark-mode option with localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm implementing dark-mode on my website, using the following script:

```
NioApp.ModeSwitch = function() {
    var toggle = $('.dark-switch');
    if($body.hasClass('dark-mode')){
        toggle.addClass('active');
    }else {
        toggle.removeClass('active');
    }
    toggle.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $body.toggleClass('dark-mode');
    })
    
}
```

And I want to store the user option, so after reload it stays either dark or light mode.

I've tried adding the following:

`localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', "true");` to the script after `$body.toggleClass('dark-mode');` and then add the following script to the main page:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode') === 'true') {
    document.getElementByClass('dark-mode').classList.add('active');
}
```

But it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from the snippets I see no reason for it not to work.
have you tried checking if its actually saved it in the storage?

Comment: @BrunoNoriller just checked, and ineed it's not saving it memory

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `getElementByClass()`.

You can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```js
document.querySelector('.dark-mode').classList.add('active');
```

Comment: dont forget the period before "dark-mode": ...querySelector('.dark-mode')...

Comment: @MatievisTheKat Oh yes, missed that one. Thanks for the mention.